In The Good The Bad And The Ugly, why did Tuco call Clint Eastwood "Blondie?"
I don't know if Blondie was his name, but Tuco also asked someone, "Did you see a blonde guy?" referring to Eastwood.
I'm thinking maybe it was a casting error and they caught it too late

He's called 'Blondie' because his hair is (relatively) blond, at least according to the film's official novelisation, based on the shooting script. It contains this exchange.

“Look, Man from Nowhere With No Name,” Tuco burst out with a touch of
irritation. “Suppose I saw a cocked gun aimed at your back and you
didn’t know it was there. By the time I yelled, ‘Man From Nowhere With
No Name, look behind you—’ you would be stone dead. So I will give you
a name. Because of your hair, I will call you Blondie. So if you hear
me yell, ‘Blondie, behind you—’ you will know I am not talking to my
horse.”

You can see from the set photos that Clint has blond highlights in his hair and from a certain angle (and in the sunlight) his hair appears quite fair, at least in comparison to his hispanic castmates.



His hair often looks brown depending on the lighting, but Clint's hair is actually what we call "dark blond" (or "dirty blond" but that term has become less used recently since nobody likes somebody calling their hair dirty). The distinction between light brown and dark blond is kind of subtle but IIRC it has to do with whether bright light brings out gold or red highlights.

In Spanish, anything that's even a bit light can be referred to as "rubio", which is translated back to English as "blond".  See this reddit question for some discussion
